# Connection between the cases in "The Sign of Three"

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In the episode [The Sign of Three (S03E02)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2781042/), Sherlock remembers that Tessa knew John's middlename and this is how he figures out the whole thing about the Mayfly Man and his attempt to assassinate one of the guests.

I didn't really understand the connection between him dating the women and attending the wedding. I mean, he was the photographer, so he did not need a date for the wedding. And if Tessa was not invited, but only saw the photographer's invitation, why would the killer need to date those women?

So, what was the purpose of dating the various women?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He was the *stand-in* photographer, implying that, having discovered that his target was to attend the wedding he put things in motion to ensure that he would be there.

The women were all employees of his target.  By dating the women, he was trying to find some information about his target that would enable him to carry out an attack.

Tessa saw the target's invitation, not the photographer's.  She evidently let some details slip to the Mayfly Man.  Perhaps some ill-considered pillow-talk.

Comment: @Dredd, how did you get that from what I wrote?

Comment: i tried to edit my comment it wouldn't let me to update it for some reason. well my qn was how do you know that all women worked for Sholto?

Comment: @Dredd IMO this episode is very weak with logic and connection. Return to the topic SH said that all women had some **secret** which was working for Sholto. So MayFly choose all women because of their employer.